# Merge Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists: (list1, list2) and I need to merge these lists to another list which contains `list1` and `list2` in this order:

- listNew = [list1(i), list2(i), list1(i+1), list2(i+1), ...]

I tried this:

```
listNew = list1 + list2    
for i in listNew:
    listNew.append(i)
    hranyNew.append(pocetHran/2+i)
```

but got an error saying:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

And another question, how can I compare `listNew[i]` and `listNew[i+1]` with `listNew[i+2]` and `listNew[i+3]`?

In another words, I need to compare all adjacent pairs with `pair+1`, `2` and so on..
Thanks!

Comment: `listNew = [y for x in zip(list1, list2) for y in x]` should do the first question.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want

Comment: maybe another question, how can create listNew[list1(i)list2(i),list1(i+1)list2(i+1),..) ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.  Could you possibly give an example?

Comment: list1=[a,b,c,d,e]
list2=[f,g,h,i,j]
and listNew should looks [af,bg,ch,di,ej]

Comment: What do you expect to get from that?  You have `list1`, `list2`, and `listNew`.  What else is it that you are looking for?

Comment: In list1 are input vertex of edges and in list2 contains output vertex. And I need find if there is multiple edges.

Comment: Ah, I looked before you edited your comment.  To get that, use `[x+y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: Thanks, that really helps

Answer (score 5):

I want to point out the very convenient [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from itertools import chain

list1 = ['1','2','3']
list2 = ['a','b','c']

listNew = list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list1, list2)))
# listNew = ['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c']
```

You could also use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a double-loop:

```
listNew = [y for x in zip(list1, list2) for y in x]
# listNew = ['1', 'a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c']
```

If you want to concatenate pairs of elements in your `listNew`, that is simply:

```
listNew_ = [x + y for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
# listNew_ = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Comment: Nice set of options; upvoted. For concatenating pairs you can get even more clever pushing all the work to the C layer in CPython: `from operator import concat`, `listNew = list(map(concat, list1, list2))`

Answer (score 0):

```
merged_list = []
length = min([len(list1), len(list2)])
for l in range(0,length):
   merged_list.append(list1[l])
   merged_list.append(list2[l])

print merged_list
```