# regular expression for data sorting in python

Tags: python, list

I have two list of list data and I am trying to concatenate the two list of data in python. I used regular expression in extracting data from my desired file and collected the required fields by creating a list. For example if the list 1 and list 2 has data:

```
lst1 = [['60', '27702', '1938470', '13935', '18513', '8'], ['60', '32424', '1933740', '16103', '15082', '11'], ['60', '20080', '1946092', '9335', '14970', '2']]

lst2 = [['2', '1'], ['11', '1'], ['12', '1']]
```

I will like to see the data like below:

```
lst3 = [[60, 27702, 1938470, 13935, 18513, 8, 2, 1],

[60, 32424, 1933740, 16103, 15082, 11, 11, 1],

[60, 20080, 1946092, 9335, 14970, 2, 12, 1]]
```

How do I receive lst3 ??

Comment: 8,4,1 should probably be 8,2,1, can you confirm / [edit] your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append list to second list (concatenate lists)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421/how-to-append-list-to-second-list-concatenate-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881399/merge-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just interleave both sublists using `zip`, and convert the joined list members to integers in a list comprehension:

```
lst3 = [[int(x) for x in l1+l2] for l1,l2 in zip(lst1,lst2)]
```

result

```
[[60, 27702, 1938470, 13935, 18513, 8, 2, 1],
[60, 32424, 1933740, 16103, 15082, 11, 11, 1],
[60, 20080, 1946092, 9335, 14970, 2, 12, 1]]
```

Comment: hi, can I see the data row wise ? like each of the sub list in rows.

Comment: you mean like `[(60, 60, 60), (27702, 32424, 20080), (1938470, 1933740, 1946092), (13935, 16103, 9335), (18513, 15082, 14970), (8, 11, 2), (2, 11, 12), (1, 1, 1)]` ?

Comment: not actually. Like :    60, 27702, 1938470, 13935, 18513, 8, 2, 1  in the first row then  60, 32424, 1933740, 16103, 15082, 11, 11, 1  in the next row...

Comment: that's already the case. The result is a list of rows. Put that in a `csv` using `writerows` you get your rows.